# How to send a Gnosis smart contract transaction through uniswap

Tags: uniswap, smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I have created my ERC20 smart contract on uniswapv2 router and deployed it on the ethereum rinkeby network. I need to use Gnosis Safe to send a multisig transaction through uniswap. kindly need assistance on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Walletconnect app from the Gnosis Safe Web UI

Comment: Thanks but i want to automate the process and do that at the codebase level

Comment: Then you can take a look on the sources for [safe-cli](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli). It uses `gnosis-py` to do all the process. If you are more a JS person, then [safe-tasks](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-tasks) is your place